# Wordpress вывод произвольного поля как meta-description

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Использую плагин ACF для настройки вывода пользовательского контента через произвольные поля.
Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением задачи — вывод содержимого произвольных полей как title и description страницы/записи.

Хочется быть уверенным, что со стороны клиента никаких казусов в плане добавления мета данных записей не будет. Человек добавляет новую запись, редактирует контент через произвольные поля, а нужные мета-данные записи подтягиваются из контента текущей записи.

Спасибо!

Comment: А не проще ли поставить для этих целей любой подходящий SEO-плагин?

Comment: Проще, но хотелось бы по возможности избежать установки плагина, чтобы не нагружать проект.

Comment: Большинство людей путают фриланс-биржу и стаковерфлоу

Comment: Большинство людей в принципе не понимают, что такое стакоферфлоу, что не мешает оставлять комментарии не по теме.